# python: how to insert elements in numpy array in a loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the following format:

`{1: 7, 2: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, ...}`

The dictionary can be potentially very large, so I decided to use `numpy` library for more efficient work with vectors.

Now I need to insert *values* from the above dictionary in a `numpy` vector (1-dimensional array) at the `key` index. So tried naively the following:

```
import numpy as np

d = {1: 7, 2: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1}
T = np.zeros(shape=(n), dtype=np.int16)

for k, v in d.items():
    N = np.insert(T, k, v)

print(N)
```

However `insert` method always returns `new` array, and overwrites `N` in my example. So what is the right way to change array elements, just as I'd do in C, e.g. `T[0] = 1`.

Looks like `numpy` does not allow this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
As suggested by Divakar, the solution is to assign multiple values at once:

`T[list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())`

And this does not require a loop.

Comment: What is the `n` parameter?

Comment: `T[list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())`?

Comment: @Divakar, thanks a lot. This is indeed very elegant solution, Where does it say that `numpy` array object can take a list as parameter?

Comment: Not sure how you were lead to `numpy array object taking a list as parameter`. It's a simple integer based indexding - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Comment: @Divakar, I'm newbie in Python. In your comment you did `list(d.keys())` which returns a list of keys from dictionary, and then submit it as index to `T` object.

Comment: @Mark You can index arrays with arrays or lists, works the same way. Similarly, the assignment values could be off arrays or lists.

Comment: Don't edit your Q with the solution... just accept the solution that works.

Answer (score 3):

In `numpy` `np.insert` makes a new array by splitting the original  array and inserting one or more values someplace in the middle.

```
In [193]: arr = np.arange(6)                                                    
In [194]: arr                                                                   
Out[194]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [195]: np.insert(arr, 2, 100)                                                
Out[195]: array([  0,   1, 100,   2,   3,   4,   5])
```

Sometimes people talk about adding a value to an array, but `+' is elementwise numeric addition

```
In [196]: arr + 10                                                              
Out[196]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
In [197]: 'one '+'two'        # string 'addition'                                                          
Out[197]: 'one two'
```

'assign a value(s)' is probably the clearest description of what you want to do.  You want to modify an element of the original array, without changing its size.

```
In [198]: arr[3] = 100                                                          
In [199]: arr                                                                   
Out[199]: array([  0,   1,   2, 100,   4,   5])
```

@Divakar's idea assigns multiple values at once:

```
In [200]: arr[[1,2]] = [100,200]                                                
In [201]: arr                                                                   
Out[201]: array([  0, 100, 200, 100,   4,   5])
```